# How to remove the N th target word(='remove_mark') in a line by sed?

Tags: shell, sed

I am learning sed of shell.
I tried the following code,

```
echo "one tworemove_markthree fourremove_markfive" | sed -E "s?(.*)remove_mark(.*)?\1\2?"
```

I expected the output of this is

```
one twothree fourremove_markfive
```

But the output of above code is following,

```
one tworemove_markthree fourfive
```

The first remove_mark is remained but the second one is removed.
However I would like to remove the first one. How to do it? And How to removed all of matched target word? Thank you very much.

Comment: Your title doesn't seem to match up with your question - which word do you want to remove, i.e. what is your desired output? Please [edit] your question to show us exactly what you want and change the title, if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By just matching `remove_mark` and replacing with nothing.

**Example**

```
$ echo "one tworemove_markthree fourremove_markfive" | sed 's/remove_mark//'
one twothree fourremove_markfive
```

---

To remove all the targets, use `g`(global) modifier.

**Example**

```
$ echo "one tworemove_markthree fourremove_markfive" | sed 's/remove_mark//g'
one twothree fourfive
```